# how to show template result only when the query returns 0 rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

A query returns multiple rows in some environments but returns 0 rows in the other environments. I want to know all results in one output in the same format, so I wrote the query below. However, it works as I intended when the former part of the query returns 0 rows, but when it returns some rows, it returns an extra row. How to not show the latter query result when the former query returns rows?

```sql
SELECT
  id, name 
FROM
  members
WHERE
  some_condition_goes_here
UNION
SELECT 0 as id, 'No results' as name FROM DUAL
```

Actual results:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | No results |

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 6 | Kate |
| 0 | No results |

The last row (id = 0) is not needed in this case.

Expected results:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | No results |

or

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 6 | Kate |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CTE wrapping the original query

```
with cte as (
    SELECT
      id, name 
    FROM
      members
    WHERE
      some_condition_goes_here
)
SELECT id, name 
FROM cte
UNION
SELECT 'no results' as id, 'no_results' as name 
FROM DUAL
WHERE not exists( select 1 from cte);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; example is based on Scott's sample `EMP` table. It selects rows based on `DEPTNO` column value. There are no employees who work in department `-5`.

```
SQL> select job, ename
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = &&par_deptno
  4  union all
  5  select 'no results', 'no results' from dual
  6  where not exists (select null
  7                    from emp
  8                    where deptno = &&par_deptno);
Enter value for par_deptno: 10

JOB        ENAME
---------- ----------
MANAGER    CLARK
PRESIDENT  KING
CLERK      MILLER

SQL> undefine par_deptno
SQL> /
Enter value for par_deptno: -5

JOB        ENAME
---------- ----------
no results no results

SQL>
```